# Differential equations for the LC circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, charge, capacitance, inductance

On wikipedia one can find that the DE for an LC circuit is given by $$\ddot I+\frac{1}{LC}I=0$$In one of my papers however I found the equation $$\ddot Q+\frac{1}{LC}Q=0$$ and I've been confused by that. I see that we could plug $I=\dot Q$ into the first equation and integrate both sides. But in order to obtain the second equation the constant on the right side (by integrating $0$) would have to be $0$ again. Can I arbitrarily choose this? Or is the second equation wrong in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential equation for LC circuits is acutually the second one. The voltage of a coil is $V_L=L\dot{I}=L\ddot{Q}$, while the voltage of a capacitor is $V=Q/C$. Both voltages must sum up to zero (assuming there is no voltage source):

$$\ddot{Q}+\frac{Q}{LC}=0$$

The derivative of the above equation repect to time gives

$$\ddot{I}+\frac{I}{LC}=0$$

which is equal to your first equation. There is no constant in any equation because we derived one of them differentiating the other one, not integrating it.

Comment: I see. In all my tabulars and note books I only ever find the equation including $I$ - but is it correct to say that this equation is derived from the DE for $Q$ and not vice versa?

Comment: Yes, the DE for $I$ is derived from the DE for $Q$ and not vice versa

Comment: @RedLantern You only find the equation for $I$ because $I$ is more useful that $Q$ in practical applications. For example measuring $I$ is very easy compared with measuring $Q$ directly. The most practical way to measure $Q$ would be to measure $V$ and $C$, but for "real world" capacitors $C$ is a nonlinear function of $V$, $\dot V$, temperature, etc - and real world capacitors also have non-zero (and non-linear!) parasitic $R$ and $L$ components...

Answer (score 2):

The Kirchoff law is $L\frac{dI}{dt}+\frac{Q}{C}=0$ with $I=\frac{dQ}{dt}$ so $L\frac{{{d}^{2}}Q}{d{{t}^{2}}}+\frac{Q}{C}=0$